# Alter the quickbuild in texmaker?

Tags: texmaker, unix

Is is possible to alter the quickbuild in texmaker such that it performs these command, without i have to it manually everytime.. The issue here is the last command, being `makeglossary`.

Commands i want quick build to execute is

`PdfLatex + bib(la)tex + PdfLatex + PdfLatex + makeglossary % + PdfLatex + View pdf`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, go to Options -- Configure TexMaker. On left side of requester select QuickBuild.  Now select the USER option, Use the wizard to build your desired sequence of commands.  Provided you have properly installed your version of TeX you now have the correct command.

The following is the command string that my system built that works.

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex|bibtex %|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex|makeindex "build\%.idx"|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex|"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf
```

Edit #1
From the top menu, select options, then 'Configure Texmaker'.
On this screen, it is important that you select for the Pdf Viewer the correct external viewer for your system.  Use the browse button right of the path window to allow you to browse for the appropriate system pdf viewer.

Now on the left margin select the Quick Build Icon.  You will now see the following requestor.

[image]

Choose the wizard circled in the picture above.  Now you will see the following picture.

[image]

Now select the commands in the order you want them to be executed in.  After you select each command select 'add'.

Comment: why acrobat at the end.. i am running this on a unix system, so your path isn not valid here..

Comment: @Lamda My system is Windows 10 and I use the acrobat reader for pdf viewing.  If you use the TexMaker wizard (far right in the User Requestor for quickbuild) it should find your installed viewer (or you can browse for it. )

Comment: under  which command?.. I can't seem to find the internal one?

Comment: @Lambda you can replace Adobe with evince in thah command (or your pdf viewer of preference).